# Looking for a Best Practice: Communication between 2 Applications for Filebrowsing and Download

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets

I'm sorry if this Question is redundant but I'm totaly confused and I need some advice for a Best Practice. It's just for learning purposes but for me this is important because I want to figure out how to do things in the best way.

I want to create an application that let's me Browse the Filesystem of my second PC over the Internet connection, not the lokal Network. So, on PC1 I want to have a small Application (App1) that shows the Filesystem in something like a Listbox with simple Navigation (Doubleclick to open a Folder ad a Button to go up one Level in the Filesystem) and a Download function that let's me Download a File from this PC an on PC2 is the counterpart (App2) that interacts with the Application on PC1. App2 reads the Fileysystem and sends the Folder and Filenames to App1 and App1 asks App2 then to get a specific File.

Now I have to specific Questions:

1. What technology is the best for communication between those to applications while communicating over the internet? WCF? My own protocol over a socket connection? Something else?
2. How can I manage to download a big File in several session? If the connection drops I want to resume the download and not start all over again.

I hope someone can give me a hint

Thank you very much

CaptnCrash

Answer (score 2):

Use the FTP protocol for this. On the second PC install and configure an FTP server application, and then in your C# client code, use something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftpclient/ to do the FTP protocol work.

Alternately, if you really need encryption of communications, use HTTPS which means configuring a web server on the second PC and using something like the System.NET classes to implement a web client.

Whatever you do, do not write your own protocol and do leverage existing .NET libraries to handle the lower level FTP or HTTP communications.

Comment: Does FTP allow for partial downloads that can be continued after a dropped connection?

Comment: As long as the FTP server supports the SIZE extension you can do this. If your FTP client library doesn't support partial downloads then use this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PartialFTPDownloader.aspx to write your own FTP code.